# Suspension is simply connected if $X$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> The suspension of a path connected topological space is simply connected.

I have questions about the following proof:

> Note that $\Sigma X = X \times I / ( X \times \partial I \cup \{x_0\}
>  \times I )$, where $x_0$ is assumed to be the base point of $X$ and
> $\partial I = \{0,1\}$.
>
> Taking any loop $f: [0,1] \to \Sigma X$, one can define the following
> homotopy: $$ H(x, t) = [(f(x), 1-t)] $$ where for any $\alpha \in X
>  \times I$, $[\alpha]$ denotes its equivalence class in $\Sigma X$.
>
> Use the universal property of quotient spaces to show that this map is
> continuous, and check that it is also a homotopy. This will show that
> every loop is homotopic to the constant loop, and thus, $\pi_1(X) =
>  0$.   As for connectedness of $\Sigma X$, just note that $X$ is
> connected, so $X \times I$ is connected, and quotients of connected
> spaces are connected, therefore $\Sigma X$ is connected.

Why is this $H$ a homotopy between a loop $f$ and the constant loop? We have $H_0(x)=[(f(x),1)]$ which is always the same point for all $x$ by the definition of the suspension. So it is constant. Same for $H_1(x)$. However, I don't understand how this helps us. For showing simple connectedness, we must show $\pi_1(\Sigma X,z)=1 \, \forall z\in \Sigma X$. So take an arbitrary $z=(x,i) \in \Sigma X$. Then we need that a loop $f$ with basepoint $z$ is homotop to $c_z$ where $c_z$ is the constant loop on $z$. But $H_0(x)$ is not constant on $z$, it is constant on one of the endings of the suspension. Also, for having a homotopy between $f$ and $c_z$, we would need $H_1(x)=f(x)$, which also isn't the case. Both $H_0$ and $H_1$ are constant loops on the endings of the suspension.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the definition of $H$ at all. $f(x)$ is already an element of $\Sigma X$. Then what is $[(f(x),1-t)]$ supposed to mean? Where did you get that proof from?

Comment: I think the standard proof would use the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Its seems that you found the above "proof" in an answer to [Simply connected reduced suspension on path connected X](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195076).

As you suspect, this does not work.

Another problem is that you consider the *reduced suspension* of a pointed sapce $(X,x_0)$. For the *unreduced suspension* there is a fairly simple proof based on the Seifert - van Kampen theorem. See my answer to [Fundamental group of the $m$-fold suspension of a finite discrete space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3069740). Unfortunately this proof does not work for the reduced suspension.

If $(X,x_0)$ is well-pointed (which means that the inclusion $\{ x_0\} \to X$ is a cofibration), then it is well-known that the quotient map from the unreduced to the reduced suspension is a homotopy equivalence. Thus for a well-pointed path connected $(X,x_0)$ the reduced suspension is simply connected.

I do not know whether this is true also for non-well-pointed $(X,x_0)$. The other answer to [Simply connected reduced suspension on path connected X](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195076) invokes the [Freudenthal suspesnsion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195076), but this only applies to pointed CW-complexes.